# Adding an icon to a website link using attribute selectors

Tags: html, css

I know how to link to.pdfs and whatnot, but I am not sure how to link to a website.

```
<p><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></p>
```

CSS

```
a[href$="http://www.google.edu"] <!--Don't know what to put here.--> {
background-image: url('pdficon_small.png') no-repeat center left;
padding-left: 25px;
background-size: auto 100%;}
```

Answer (score 4):

For links with pdf files you can simply add this on your css file (you can replace image with your own image) :

```
a[href$="pdf"]{
background-image: url('http://www.mgsdist.com/img/pdf_icon.png') no-repeat center left;
padding-left: 25px;
background-size: auto 100%;}
```

Your code contains something like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/pdf.pdf">pdf download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

This will exact href `http://www.google.edu`:

```
a[href="http://www.google.edu"]{
background-image: url('pdficon_small.png') no-repeat center left;
padding-left: 25px;
background-size: auto 100%;}
```

This will match any href starting with `http://`:

```
a[href^="http://"]{
background-image: url('pdficon_small.png') no-repeat center left;
padding-left: 25px;
background-size: auto 100%;}
```

This will set for all links which extension is pdf:

```
a[href$="pdf"]{
background-image: url('pdficon_small.png') no-repeat center left;
padding-left: 25px;
background-size: auto 100%;}
```

This will set containing href value `google`:

```
a[href*="google"]{
background-image: url('pdficon_small.png') no-repeat center left;
padding-left: 25px;
background-size: auto 100%;}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... No icon is showing up. The problem may be that google.edu is being referenced in another attribute. I'm not sure how to differentiate between this attribute and the previous one because they both use the url google.com, only this last one links to a website where the previous one links to a pdf and gif.

Comment: @Darren in that comment above, the hrefs are not valid. You **must** include `http://` at the start of all urls.

Comment: Accidentally posted the wrong link. Here's an updated link on my code: http://jsfiddle.net/5oynkg8z/. I still can't get the last icon to show